# Re-render only changed section of Marionette.js CollectionView

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, marionette

Below is the code I currently have that re-renders a collectionView on every addition or removal of a model. However, it seems inefficient as it has to render the whole thing every time, when all I really need is one modelView to be removed or one to be added. So how could I achieve this?

```
var CollectionView = Marionette.CollectionView.extend({

    childView: ModelView,

    initialize: function() {
        [ "add", "remove" ].forEach(function(eventName) {
            this.listenTo(this.collection, eventName, this.render, this);
        }.bind(this));
    }

});
```

Thanks in advance for any help you can give!

Comment: Can you share an [mcve] we can play with..?

Comment: @TJ Okay, I've put an example on JSFiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/z5zs3jq0/8/) (since there's necessarily quite a few lines of code to get it working, even though I haven't included a router or any other really superfluous features). The example at the moment creates 800 ItemViews and displays them on the page through a CollectionView. When you click the delete button, the model is removed from the collection and the view is automatically re-rendered. However, the more items there are on the page, the longer it takes to re-render, which implies that it's rendering the whole thing again...

Comment: ...rather than just removing the single deleted ItemView from the DOM, which would be most efficient. For example, try changing the loop in the "start" event handler so it only creates 8 items instead of 800 and then delete one, and it does it noticeably quicker.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is already done [automatically in Marionette](http://marionettejs.com/docs/v1.7/marionette.collectionview.html#collectionview-automatic-rendering):

> When a model is added to the collection, the collection view will
>   render that one model in to the collection of item views.
>
> When a model is removed from a collection (or destroyed / deleted),
>   the collection view will close and remove that model's item view.

Comment: Interesting that you say that because it doesn't appear to work for me automatically. I'll have to look, maybe I'm doing something wrong somewhere.

Comment: I could be wrong, but I think it only updates on the page when the collectionView's `render` function is called, which I presume renders all the DOM elements again rather than just the ones that have changed.

Comment: Tholle is right - changed your example here https://jsfiddle.net/z5zs3jq0/9/
open it and open the console - you will see at first 800 renders and then every 2000 milliseconds another render for the new added item + if you delete an item you will also see one render text added to the console

Comment: @AviPinto Oh, I see, so I was actively slowing it down by listening to the add and remove events. I should have noticed that myself really, but thanks for editing my fiddle, very helpful!

Comment: @AviPinto The problem I'm having is that in the minimal example I posted on JSFiddle, everything works, but it doesn't work (i.e. nothing changes on deletion) when I remove those lines in my actual bigger project. I'm going to have to try and figure out why that is.

Comment: I solved the problem. Apparently, I was using an incompatible version of Backbone that stopped Marionette from working as it should have.